# Opencv c++ on Linux - Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c++, opencv, segmentation-fault

recently I have installed Opencv following the official guide (https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html) and everything seemed to work fine until I tried to use some more complex functions. For example, the following code applies a Gaussian Filter on a simple image, but when I try to execute it I get "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

This is the code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if(argc < 2) {
        std::cout << "Error: insert the image name! \n";
        return 0;
    }
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread(argv[1]);
    if(img.data == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Error: wrong name! \n";
        return 0;
    }
    cv::Mat img_grayscale(img.rows, img.cols, CV_8U);
    cv::cvtColor(img, img_grayscale, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    cv::Mat img_gaussian(img.rows, img.cols, CV_8U);
    cv::GaussianBlur(img_grayscale, img_gaussian, cv::Size(5, 5), 0, 0, cv::BORDER_DEFAULT);
    cv::imshow("image gaussian filter", img_grayscale);
    cv::waitKey(0);
}
```

and this is the compile line I run in the terminal:

```
g++ lab02_task4.cpp -o lab02_task4 -I/usr/local/include/opencv4 -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_imgproc
```

I explored a bit and I found out that the function `GaussianBlur()` is the cause. Can you help me understanding what's the problem?

Comment: Your code works on my system. Which OS do you use? You could debug your executable with `gdb` to dump the stack trace of where the segmentation fault happens.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)